# egrep regular expression for times over five minutes

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have the following time formats in a text file

```
       `1` equals one second.
    `5|01` equals five minutes and one seconds.
   `13|01` equals thirteen minutes and one seconds.
`21|12|01` equals 21 hours, 12 minutes, and 1 seconds.
```

I need to egrep for any times over five minutes. 
I'm using the following regex but it doesn't work because it excludes times such as `13|00`.

```
'[[:space:]0-9][[:space:]0-9][[:space:]|][[:space:]0-9][[:space:]6-9][|][0-9][0-9]'
```

Here's an example:

```
 lite on       1
 lite on      01
 lite on    5|22
 lite on   23|14
 lite on 1|14|23
```

Comment: `grep` alone wont solve your problem because you're not matching characters, but a condition. See `awk` http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk

Comment: Can you give an example of some of the actual output of a file containing these times? I have a couple idea's but with regex formatting is always the key.

Comment: Does it have to be `grep`? Because `regex` is amazing for matching text patterns, it's really quite poor at understanding them as values. I'd strongly suggest looking towards `perl` or `awk` instead.

Comment: @user72055, If you have one hour and one minute, is the one minuted padded with a space or a zero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignoring the spaces (which you can fill in yourself later) and possible leading zeros (likewise), you're looking to match any of

```
[5-9]\|[0-9]+
[1-9][0-9]\|[0-9]+
[0-9]+\|[0-9]+\|[0-9]+
```

for times in the range

```
[5,10) minutes
[10,99) minutes
1+ hours
```

respectively.

So join those together in a match group `(...|...)` with sufficient anchoring at the beginning and end (so you don't match on `14|59` or `1|00|00`).

This gives

```
grep -E 'on +([5-9]\|[0-9]+|[1-9][0-9]\|[0-9]+|[0-9]+\|[0-9]+\|[0-9]+) *$'
```

We can simplify a little, because the seconds are common to all three regexps:

```
grep -E 'on +([5-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]+\|[0-9]+)\|[0-9]+ *$'
```

Comment: Note: I'm assuming that `5|00` counts as "over 5 minutes" in the above, as there's probably a truncated fractional second hiding there...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't something like 0|0|3 pass your filter? I'd check that the leftmost [x-9]|... is [1-9] and not [0-9]

Comment: OP's examples don't specify testings for validity, so you are  probably correct. however, filtering for 0|01|13 should be simple enough by requiring [1-9] on each leftmost range in the group, no?

Comment: @Dani: I did start by ignoring leading zeros - if they may be present, then it's simple to account for them, as you say.  Keeping regexps simple always depends on how much you can assume about the format; here, it appears to be machine-generated rather than written by humans, so let's capitalise on that!

Comment: I know the OP explicitly requested a regex, but I'm really not sure that that's the tool to be using for this job. Regex really isn't particularly good at numeric comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
grep -E '( [0-9]{1,2}\|[0-9]{1,2}\|[0-9][1-9] )|( [0-9][0-9]\|[0-9]{2,2} )|( [5-9]\|[0-9][1-9] )|( [6-9]\|[0-9][0-9] )' <file>
```

Basically you are creating 4 patterns encased in `()`'s separated by `|`'s. the `|`'s act as `or` in the regex.

the `{1,2}` parts are `1-2 instances of preceding pattern` so `[0-9]{1,2}` means `1-2 instances of 0-9`

After which we create a basic test case for all your possible digit combinations's via the `or` syntax

Comment: @Dani_l No no no, Nitpick away. Its one of those day's where I apparently can't brain at all. Thanks for keeping an eye out.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `grep`. Regular expressions are for matching patterns, but they're really horrible for matching values. You can probably do it, but you're using a hammer as a screwdriver. Technically it works, but it's messy and inefficient.

So instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @numbers = m/(\d+)/g;
    my $seconds = pop(@numbers);
    $seconds += ( pop(@numbers) // 0 ) * 60;  #second digit minutes -> seconds
    $seconds
        += ( pop(@numbers) // 0 ) * 60 * 60;  #third digit, hours  -> seconds;
    print if $seconds > 300;
}

__DATA__
 lite on       1
 lite on      01
 lite on    5|22
 lite on   23|14
 lite on 1|14|23
```

This prints:

```
 lite on    5|22
 lite on   23|14
 lite on 1|14|23
```

You can one-liner-ify this as:

```
perl -ne 'for ( m/(\d+)/g ) { $t *= 60; $t += $_ }; print if $t > 300;'
```

For bonus points - this copes with fairly arbitrary validation criteria, without too much difficulty, and doesn't require anywhere near as much mucking around if you decide to grep for a different value one day.

But the above works by:

- use `m/(\d+)/g` - as a `g` match, means it selects repeated instances of "one or more digits" into an array. (`@numbers` or just as a self contained iterator in the for loop in the second example).
- it converts that chain of digits to seconds by mutiplying up by 60. (This won't work so well if you ever add days to it!)
- And then tests that number for being greater than 300 - which is 5 minutes in seconds.